# Hover off transition css

Tags: css, animation, hover, transition

this question might be obvious but i'm new in css.

I'm animating a shape so when you hover it, it stretches. I've completed the hover on with a nice ease transition but when you move off the mouse the transition doesn't work. Is there a way to make it happen also in the hover off moment?

```
.shape1{
position: absolute;
background:red
top:512px;
width:180px;
height:140px;
}

.shape1:hover {
height: 160px;
top:492px;
transition: 0.2s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Your answer

You have added the `transition` property on the hover state of the element. Therefore the `transition` is not applied when you leave the `cursor` from the element.

```
.shape1{
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    top: 512px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 140px;
    transition: .2s ease; /* move this here from :hover */
}
```

#### Further information

Besides this you can also add specific properties to the `transition`. For example, if you only want the height to be animated you could it like this:

```
.shape1 {
    transition: height .2s ease;
    /* this inly affects height, nothing else */
}
```

You can even define different transition-times for each property:

```
.shape1 {
    transition: height .2s ease, background-color .5s linear;
    /* stacking transitions is easy */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the transition before the `:hover`, so the transition always applies

`.shape1 {
   transition: 0.2s ease;
}`

> The `:hover` selector is used to select elements when you mouse over them. 
>    [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Answer (score 0):

When you add also transition to your shape1 class it should works